# How to display deep nested forum names?

Tags: hyperlinks, breadcrumbs, forum

In the backend of the company-intranet there is an area where you validate the rights of an user. Since the intranet comes with a forum, you can set rights for users to moderate a specific forum.

The problem is that there are pretty deep nested and long-titled forum names, like this one:

Technikforum WasserStrom > 04 Meisteraustausch -intern- > 2011

My solution would be to shorten the the links but leave out the first and the last name, so you can recognize which forum is mentioned. (which is important for the admin who validates the rights since they are working with sensible data)

Technikforum WasserStrom > ... > 2011

But the Problem still is that my space is limited and the best solution would be to have always a one-liner because in the future the list(attached) will grow and grow.

[image]

Please note the arrows are the seperators between the names of the forums.

Another possible solution would be to just display the forum where the user gets the rights to moderate and when you hover on it it will display the whole path of this specific forum. what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the actual problem is that there is no naming convention in the Forum names and thus you can't create an effective abbreviation or short code for the whole forum name route ( unless there is and I can't see it ). If there was, you could just use those abbreviations.

Supposing that phrases like "01 Artbeitsgreppe Datenshcutz und Revision" and dates will probably be used several times throughout the forum, it could be changed to an abbreviation, with e.g. a pattern like:

```
[ForumNo.ForumName]>[SubForumNo.SubForumName]>[Year]
```

you could have:

```
1.Forumshared Services > 1.ADUR > 2007
```

On the other hand, if all that matters is the first and the last names of the forums, you could just omit the middle just like you did.

```
Technikforum WasserStrom > ... > 2011
```

Another solution with the full name visible could be a tree like formation:

```
Technikforum WasserStrom
|_ 04 Meisteraustausch -intern-
   |__ 2011
```

where you could also omit or make smaller the less essential names.

Comment: +1 Great point about naming conventions (but how often do we see them actually used?). I think languages that often have longer representation of words like German is always difficult to accommodate for in UI design.

Answer (score 0):

So, for example, in the last line:
"John Doe 5        6forumshared services
                   >
                   01 Artbeitsgreppe Datenshcutz und Revision

The number 06 and the number 01 are they particulars articles?

If yes... I think you can use your own solution just display the forum where the user gets the rights and when you (ADMIN is right?) hover on it will display all the paths of this specific forum.

I don't know if I answer your question. :|

Anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your lack of space mainly comes from the fact that you have chosen to arrange the table/list view with the button as an additional column, which is the sensible thing to do but unfortunately you also have to accommodate wide columns due to the length of names.

An alternate layout design is to have the actions at the bottom of the row and still aligned to the right hand side, thus allow the extra width for the names to stretch over the horizontal space freed up by moving the button to the bottom row.

Answer (score 0):

I think omitting any middle sections out of the path with an ellipsis like xyz said is a great idea.

You could have the ellipsis as a toggle that shows the full path.

So, if the part in squares brackets is a link, then this...

Technikforum WasserStrom > [...] > 2011

Would become...

Technikforum WasserStrom > [04 Meisteraustausch -intern-] > 2011

I think you could also reduce the width of the name column, maybe break that onto 2 lines for first and last names.

To create even more width for your path column you could maybe swap out the REMOVE button with an icon, maybe trash can or a cross.

Maybe end up with something like this

[image]